# На планшетах не находится WebView

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.
Возникла странная проблема. Я пытаюсь загрузить html, но `WebView` нет (ссылка `null`).  
Вызов `Activity` с `WebView`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, aboutProg.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Метод `onCreate` вызываемого `Activity`

```
private String uriFile = "file:///android_asset/";
private WebView wv;
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_programm);
    wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.textAboutUsWeb);//в том месте не находит
    wv.loadUrl(uriFile+"textAboutUs.html");//а тут вылетает, потому что wv - null
}
```

И файл about_programm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#fff">

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/textAboutUsWeb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**ЗЫ.** такая проблема возникает на планшетах с **android 3.2 и 2.3**. На телефонах с **android 2.3** работает.

Comment: А ты не пробовал загружать не сразу док `(wv.loadUrl(uriFile+"textAboutUs.html")`, а например текст. Просто могут быть проблемы с путями или с правами.

Comment: дело в том, что webview ссылается на null

Comment: кнопку добавь попробуй ее найти =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуйте скомпилировать под API 12-13 c minSDK<=10
2. Планшет и телефон могут отличаться требованиями к аппаратной части - теоретически это может быть причиной. Вставьте в манифест такой "универсальный" скрипт

-

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

У меня схожая проблема решалась именно так.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, на днях у меня были проблемы с отображением интерфейса на различных экранах, и для этого я создал еще одну папку layout-xlarge. И когда добавил webview в папку layout, забыл добавить  в layout-xlarg. Соответственно, на планшетах и вылетало, а на телефонах все работало.